# NameError: name 'face_api_url' is not defined が起こる

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

"NameError: name 'face_api_url' is not defined" と問題が出てきました
face_api_url そのものを消去すると次は NameError: name 'binary_img' is not defined と出ます。
あれこれ試してますが解決方法が尽きてきてるので分かりやすく説明お願いします。
ちなみにプログラミングど素人です。

```
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }
params = { 'returnFaceId': 'true', 'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise', }
res = requests.post(face_api_url,params=params, headers=headers, data=binary_img)
```

Comment: 例えば、この記事 [PythonライブラリStreamlitを用いて顔検出アプリの作成](https://qiita.com/ryo19841204/items/74d663b08e56345e3b60) を参考に作業していて、入力したソースコードにタイプミスがあったとかでは？ 良くソースコードと参考資料を見較べてみてください。

Comment: 先にコメントした記事と、こちらの記事 [Microsoft AzureのFace APIで生田斗真とはらぱんを識別してみる](https://tech.mof-mof.co.jp/blog/face-api-ikemen/) の混合になっているような感じですね。質問に提示されているソースは[動画](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpBjbK6jic0)の40:16頃から表示されているセル1つだけに相当する内容ですが、再現・調査・回答のためには`import requests`から始まる全てのセルの内容が必要です。それらを含めてソースコードを提示してください。あるいは自分で入力した内容を動画と1対1で見較べてみてください。何かしら入力不足やタイプミスがあると思われます。

Answer (score 1):

> "NameError: name 'face_api_url' is not defined" と問題が出てきました

[変数が定義されていない](https://techacademy.jp/magazine/23062)時に起こるエラーです。
下記のように`face_api_url`をあらかじめ宣言しておかないとpythonが`face_api_url`とは何のことか分からずに`'変数名' is not defined`エラーを表示します。

```
# 左記サイトからコードを流用 https://qiita.com/ryo19841204/items/74d663b08e56345e3b60
endpoint = 'https://20YYMMDDxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/' # AzureのAPIエンドポイント
face_api_url = endpoint + 'face/v1.0/detect'
```

エンドポイントの取得方法は[Youtubeの解説動画](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpBjbK6jic0)の32分までの流れで説明されています。

`binary_img`も同様のエラーが発生しています。
`binary_img`変数には、インターネットから取得またはパソコンに保存した画像データを格納する必要があります。

格納する方法は多岐にわたりますので、私の回答では扱いません。
別の問題が発生した場合は[再現可能な短いサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を作成して[新しい質問をする](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3345/9820)ことをお勧めします。